# MethodNotAllowedHttpException when i only submit html iframe code

Tags: php, laravel

[image]

I have a form with post method and there is a field named 'videoUrl', I want to submit a whole youtube embade code, but when i submit that code i get this error and the REQUEST_METHOD was changed to GET method !! This problem is occured only production server not local server!

> Hence it was submit successfully when i put text rather than iframe code.

Here is my html code.

```
<form action="{{route('newsSubmit')}}" method="post">
@csrf
    <input type="text" name="videoUrl">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Here is the route.

```
Route::post('newsSubmit', 'AdminController@newsSubmit')->name('newsSubmit');
```

Comment: have you added @csrf field?

Comment: also run php artisan route:clear

Comment: sorry i added @csrf, i forgot to write here

Comment: after clear route, cache and config then i upload it on server

Comment: it works when i put pure text but when i put iframe code like ``` <iframe width="545" height="409" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Yie9Bgo69m8" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>``` this, i got that error.

Comment: where is your iframe code? do you mean when you add the iframe code in the textbox.

Comment: Yes exactly, i put the whole iframe code in textbox

Comment: why you are passing an iframe code in the textbox. if you are trying to save it in database, then it's wrong. you should save only the content and then show that content in iframe later when you need it

Comment: i know that, there is a number of way to bypass it, but what is the solution of this problem?